# Entity Framework change column value before comparing

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a table with a column that I need to change it's values before comparing with a `.Where()`.

Take this example: if the value in db is 'My sTriNg', I want to transform to 'my_string' before comparing.

Is there a lightweight algorythm to do this?

UPDATE: So after the answer I realized that I can do this:

```
public static string RemoveAccentsAndSpaceFromField(this string sNomenclature)
    {
        StringBuilder sbReturn = new StringBuilder();
        var arrayText = sNomenclature.ToLowerInvariant().Normalize(NormalizationForm.FormD).ToCharArray();
        foreach (char letter in arrayText)
        {
            if (CharUnicodeInfo.GetUnicodeCategory(letter) != UnicodeCategory.NonSpacingMark)
                sbReturn.Append(letter);
        }

        string sNoAccents = sbReturn.ToString();

        string sNoSpaces = sNoAccents.Replace(" ", "_");

        return sNoSpaces;
    }
```

Then use it like this:

```
using (var oContext = new MyContext())
{
    bool bFieldExists = oContext.Fields.Any(s => s.Nomenclature.RemoveAccentsAndSpaceFromField() == sFieldName && s.id != iFieldId);
}
```

Comment: How do you define "light weight"? Please show what you tried to give us something to compare with a possible better solution.

Comment: If `oContext.Fields` is an `IQueryable` from EF I can't imagine that this works. There's no way to translate `s.Nomenclature.RemoveAccentsAndSpaceFromField()` into SQL.

Comment: @GertArnold the type of oContext.Fields is DbSet<MyContext.Fields>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to transform the actual value. You can do this.

```
string StringToCompare = "my_string";

var FilteredList = DbContext.TableName
     .Where(i => i.ColumnName.ToLower().Replace(' ', '_') == StringToCompare.ToLower())
     .ToList();
```

Comment: Actually i needed to do more than just replace and to lower, but I created an extension for `string` and used inside linq expression and it worked. I tought that I can't use a method of mine inside linq, but seems that `string` extension is fine to use!